# need help for multi-site Google Analytic

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I need to write a code on IF condition but i stuck how do i do it.

I have one multi sites WordPress websites (with domain Maping) and I trying to add google analytical  individual single-site trackers change if url change for that.

e.g. I writing code to inject GA code if domain is "mydomain.com"

```
<?php if (bloginfo('mydomain.com')) { ?>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-7567xxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

<?php } ?>
```

but result was not what i expected any one can help me with this if I need change in result if domain change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figure out there little error in your code : **$siteURL**

```
    <?php 

  // Set your domain
  $siteURL = "http://www.example.com/";

  // Match with the get_site_url function
  if($siteURL == get_site_url()) { ?>

  <!-- your JS/HTML goes code here -->

  <?php  } ?>
```

Thank you so much Flux for help

Answer (score 0):

`bloginfo` will use the title of your blog.

To get the URL you can try this code:

```
<?php 

  // Set your domain
  $siteURL = "http://www.example.com/";

  // Match with the get_site_url function
  if($siteurl == get_site_url()) { ?>

  <!-- your JS/HTML goes code here -->

  <?php  } ?>
```

This way you can use php varible to set a url or blog id and execute the GA code  with your if/else statement. you can also use php array for multiple settings.

Comment: <?php 

  // Set your domain
  $siteURL = "http://myurl";

  // Match with the get_site_url function
  if($siteurl == get_site_url()) { ?>

    <h1>YES It's Works</h1>
  
  <?php  } ?>    
<!-- Above my codes-->